# Binding a "new map" results to an object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, optimization, query-optimization

I'm creating a heavy HQL query and try to optimize it. There is a table `Product`, which needs some statistics calculated for every single product, lets call it `stat`. I'm trying this kind of query to fetch all products and their stats at once (this is a simplified query, real one is much more complex):

```
select new map(min(product) as prod, sum(somestat) as stat) 
from Product product
  left join product.stats somestat
group by product.id, product.name
order by product.name
```

However, when I try to execute this kind of query, first it executes the primary select, and then it executes X times `SELECT product.* FROM product WHERE product.id=?` selecting every product that was returned.

Is there a way to make it take the results from the first query to create those Product instances?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `min(product)`? Shouldn't there be a specific column of product? Same for `somestat`. Grouping by both `product.id` and `product.name` also seems wrong.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I'm trying to fetch the whole product (rather than some of it's fields) and make hibernate bind it to Product object. It does that, however by using an extra query. `min` is required because of `group`. `group` is required because of join (I need to sum all of the stats for each kind of product). `group by product.name` is required to use it in `order by`, and I'm sure the column has unique values.

Comment: If you want the whole product, then hibernate is already doing the only reasonable thing: executing N+1 selects. You happen to group by the primary key so theoretically one could imagine doing it, but you can't select any columns not used in group-by. Anyway, such custom trickery is beyond an ORM such as Hibernate.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik That's a shame, I was hoping for it to execute exactly that kind of trickery :D Ok, I'm staying with my current solution of doing "select product from Product product" before executing my query, which makes hibernate bind everything together. Thanks again, and if you post your last comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the whole product, then hibernate is already doing the only reasonable thing: executing N+1 selects. You happen to group by the primary key so theoretically one could imagine doing it, but even in SQL you are not allowed to select any columns not used in group-by. Anyway, such custom trickery is beyond an ORM such as Hibernate.